# QTMovieCurrentSizeAttribute and QTMovieSizeDidChangeNotification replacements

Tags: quicktime, qtkit

Does anyone know the correct way to replace old `QTMovieCurrentSizeAttribute` and  `QTMovieSizeDidChangeNotification` tasks? I'm trying to clean out old deprecated code.

I've found that `QTMovieNaturalSizeDidChangeNotification` is not a replacement for `QTMovieSizeDidChangeNotification`. Likewise `QTMovieNaturalSizeAttribute` is not a replacement for `QTMovieCurrentSizeAttribute`. `Natural Size` refers to the `QTMovie`'s native resolution, while `Current Size` refer to the resolution at which a `QTMovie` is being displayed (this may also be the resolution to which the movie is being decoded, which can resize from native). For example, if the source was anamorphic or had non-square pixels, then `Natural` and `Current Size`s will not be the same. The difference is easily seen in the Movie Inspector Window of the QuickTime 7 Player.

As near as I can tell, QuickTime X allows multiple views into the same `QTMovie`, so the notion of `Current Size` needed to be replaced by something new. (Perhaps the `Current Size` functionality was moved into `QTMovieView`? Or a decoder query?) Can anyone refer me to documentation or sample code for the new way?

Any sample code of a Movie Inspector Window that has been updated to show `Natural` and `Current ('Actual') Sizes`, without using deprecated code, would be ideal. This has been very confusing to tackle, so far.

Answer (score 0):

Is this useful? http://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-955.66/platform/graphics/mac/MediaPlayerPrivateQTKit.mm

```
IntSize MediaPlayerPrivate::naturalSize() const
{
    if (!metaDataAvailable())
        return IntSize();

    // In spite of the name of this method, return QTMovieNaturalSizeAttribute transformed by the 
    // initial movie scale because the spec says intrinsic size is:
    //
    //    ... the dimensions of the resource in CSS pixels after taking into account the resource's 
   //    dimensions, aspect ratio, clean aperture, resolution, and so forth, as defined for the 
   //    format used by the resource

    NSSize naturalSize = [[m_qtMovie.get() attributeForKey:QTMovieNaturalSizeAttribute] sizeValue];
    return IntSize(naturalSize.width * m_scaleFactor.width(), naturalSize.height * m_scaleFactor.height());
}
```

Comment: Probably more relevant is the definition of `cacheMovieScale` in the same file, which gets an undocumented attribute with the key `@"QTMoviePreferredTransformAttribute"`, whose value is an NSAffineTransform.